# Android record screen and stream it

Tags: android, ffmpeg, stream, screen, record

I am working on a personal project in which I want to record the screen of my phone and stream it. It doesn't have to record the whole, it can be just my app. I am trying to use ffmpeg, but I see that is not possible to read from /dev/graphics/fb0 as it requires root.

I am trying to check what other options do I have. I know it must be possible, as there are other apps that do the same without the need of having a rooted device.

I have just found this class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html, that might be useful, but it is only available in API 21.

Could you give me any tips of tools, or how could I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey can you point me to any link where you found the screen recording using ffmpeg?

Comment: I don't have any link. I think if you google it there are people that compiled ffmpeg/fferver for Android. The thing is that you have to be root to be able to record the screen with that. For me it wasn't good enough.

Comment: did you find any solution? I have the same problem @AntonioCG

Answer (score 0):

This github [project](https://github.com/Truiton/ScreenCapture) is very simple and is using MediaProjection to achieve screen recording. I hope it will help with recording part.